# Can't start angular2-webpack-start

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

I am following tutorial at github:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/

I installed node+npm and run npm install. Clone git repository, run npm install and then when I want to run npm start, it fails with error message.

This is debug log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.12
3 info using node@v4.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0
6 info start angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\branislav.remen\Workspaces\Angular2-ws\test\angular2-webpack-starter
12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.3.0
15 error npm  v2.14.12
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@3.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     npm run server:dev
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Brano, real error message should be above lines you copied here.

Answer (score 0):

your npm version is relatively ancient, you should update to the latest npm 3.x.

Npm 3 introduced a lot of changes, like a maximally flat dependency tree, support for packages with strange names, etc.

all these starter tutorials run using the latest npm. No need to update node, 4.3 is OK. Try the following steps to see if it works:

- upgrade npm to npm 3
- remove node_modules
- run npm install again